# Auto map nested class in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, automapper

I have the following API classes:

```
public class ApiPlaceBetInput : ApiRequestBase
{
    public ApiDoBet DoBet { get; set; }
}

public class ApiRequestBase
{
    public ApiIdentity Identity { get; set; }
}
```

and I have the Business logic classes:

```
public class BlPlaceBetInput
{
    internal BlDoBetInput DoBet { get; set; }
    internal BlIdentity Identity { get; set; }
}
```

Where both the API and BL classes have all the same properties names.
how to map  ApiPlaceBetInput into BlPlaceBetInput using Auto mapper in .NET?
And what if the properties names were different, how can I map each element individually?

Comment: What have you tried? Using AutoMapper is correct. https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Getting-started.html

Comment: The main thing in the AutoMapper name is Auto. It should do its job automatically. If it can't do its job automatically, then the best solution is to abandon it and do the mapping manually.

Answer (score 0):

To map one property to another you need to use the options...

Here is an example mapping Phone to Telephone:

```
using AutoMapper;
using DataMapperDemo.Models;
using System;

namespace DataMapperDemp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<Author, AuthorDTO>()
                .ForMember(destination => destination.Phone,
               opts => opts.MapFrom(source => source.Telephone));

            });
            IMapper iMapper = config.CreateMapper();
            Author author = new Author()
            {
                Id = 1,
                FirstName = "Chris",
                LastName = "Catignani",
                Address = new Address()
                { Street = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    City = "TN",
                    State = "TN",
                    Country = "USA"
                },
                Telephone = "(615) 474-7777"
            };
            var destination = iMapper.Map<Author, AuthorDTO>(author);
            Console.WriteLine(destination.FirstName + "," +
                                destination.LastName + "," +
                                destination.Street + "," +
                                destination.Phone + "," +
                                destination.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I am looking for. Your phone and telephone must contain nested classes to be as same as my example.

Comment: @Artavazd All you need to do is just reference the property. destination.x.x to sourse.x.x

Comment: If it was that simple I would have done it. but It is not working that way.